# My bullet velocity won't change even when i change their variables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Update: I figuired it out.
This is my bullet code:

```cs
void SpawnBullet()
    {
        GameObject newBullet;

        //spread
        Vector3 spreadVector = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spread, spread), Random.Range(-spread, spread));

        //spawn bullet
        newBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.transform.position, firePoint.transform.rotation);

        //make bullet stay in front
        newBullet.layer = transform.parent.gameObject.layer + 1;

        //make bullet moves
        newBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = (transform.up * bulletSpeed) + spreadVector;


    }
```

Even though I had changed "spread" and "bulletSpeed" variables in the inspector, the bullets stayed the same.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a component on your bullet where an `Update` or `FixedUpdate` method is changing the `Rigidbody2D` velocity? Also, what are the `Rigidbody2D` setting in the Inspector when you select the bullet?

Comment: That doesn't look like your bullet's code, it looks like the code that spawns the bullet. There's nothing wrong with the spawning of the bullet, please show us your bullet code. And make sure that transform.up is the right direction.

Comment: You guys don't seem to know what this code does. This code spawns the bullet AND set the bullet's velocity as well. All of the variables is on my gun game object. So my bullet code only have an OnTriggerEnter2D.

Comment: What do you mean by `the bullets stayed the same.`? You know that the velocity is in **WorldSpace** so the rotation won't affect the direction. Is it possible that the RigidBody is set to `Kinematic`?

Comment: I figured it out.